# Null Object Ref when instantiating a container class in C#

Tags: c#, nested, nullreferenceexception, instantiation

I have problems to understand the following behavior of C#: if I define a class containing a nested class like this:

```
public class Container {
    public Contained instanceofContained;

        public Container()
        {
             this.instanceofContained = new Contained();
        }
}
```

and then try to  instantiate it by writting `containerinstance = new Container()`, the value of `instanceofContained` will be null. Why is this so, since the reference to the `Contained` object created in the constructor is written into the `instanceofContained` property of the `containerinstance` object, so after the constructor is finished this reference will remain so garbage collector shouldn't delete the `instanceofContained` object? But if I define the constructor like this:

```
public class Container {
    public Contained instanceofContained;

        public Container(Contained instanceofContainedref)
        {
            this.instanceofContained = instanceofContainedref;
        }
}
```

and  instantiate the `Container` class like this:

```
containedinstance = new Contained();
containerinstance = new Container(containedinstance);
```

everything is o.k. Anyone can please explain this to me?

Comment: It should work fine and not be null... Check it out: http://ideone.com/NqVVh1

Comment: It won't be null in fact I just tried this and it wasn't. What is happening inside the Contained constructor?

Comment: hmm now I tried it myself and indeed it wasn't null... but it is inside of the bigger project where the error actually occurs. Now I have no idea why this happens over there... but thanks for your answers anyway, one monkey off my back.